# ComponentDidMount and dispatching an action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I do have a React component that loads when user clicks on a ReactRouter Link such as `http://mysite/page/:id`.

Inside the ComponentDidMount method I'm using the 2 following actions:

**postsSetPage(page)**

```
should be a SYNC action that changes the page right away in the store). 
I'm passing it the id given from ReactRouter as page.
```

**postsFetch(args)**:

```
is an ASYNC action that fetches data from API.
```

So my code looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.postsSetPage(this.props.match.params.id);
    console.log(this.props.posts.query); // <========== this will not be updated
    this.props.postsFetch(this.props.posts.query);
}
```

this.props.posts.query contains all arguments to apply filter/ordering/pagination on my API. It looks like this:

```
this.props.posts == {
    records: [],
    query: {
        page: 1,
        arg1: "asdasd",
        argN: "blabla",
    },
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**
The code inside componentDidMount doesn't work because after I set the page `this.props.posts.query` hasn't updated yet (console.log is confirming) and when I call fetch action query doesn't contain the correct page.

So aren't actions such as setPage suppose to be sync?

All help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setPage` as a redux action is synchronous, but the resulting `setState` which happens due to change in redux store might not be (it's better to assume `setState` is never synchronous).

And if your `setPage` action goes through a middleware which does some async stuff (fetching data from api) and then forwarding the action, then the action itself wont' lead to `setState` call synchronously, because redux store would only change once the api data comes back.

But i guess you are facing the first problem.

One way to take care of your problem can be to do the fetch in either the action (thunked), or do it in a middleware.

Comment: Thanks your answer was very helpful!

Comment: At the end I ended up accessing the state from the thunk directly. So now instead of calling fetch(someFilters) I do fetch() and the filters are implicitly read by the thunk from the store. Do you feel it is ok? I read somewhere it was an anti-pattern to do this, but for now, i guess, it will work.

Comment: Don't worry about the anti patterns for now. Using redux itself has given you a lot of leverage and discipline. Refactoring the code later with redux is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

As per React, this.props are the immutable object means you can not update it programmatically. 
Here you will have to use this.state